# JS.__struct__/1 is undefined, cannot expand struct JS

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I try to walk through an JS example of the LiveView 0.17.1 docs (https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/0.17.1/Phoenix.LiveView.JS.html)

So I created a new Phoenix 1.6.2 application with `mix phx.new demo3 --no-ecto` and changed the `mix.exs` deps part to this:

```elixir
  defp deps do
    [
      {:phoenix, "~> 1.6.2"},
      {:phoenix_html, "~> 3.0"},
      {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.2", only: :dev},
      {:phoenix_live_view, "~> 0.17.1"},
      {:floki, ">= 0.30.0", only: :test},
      {:phoenix_live_dashboard, "~> 0.5"},
      {:esbuild, "~> 0.2", runtime: Mix.env() == :dev},
      {:swoosh, "~> 1.3"},
      {:telemetry_metrics, "~> 0.6"},
      {:telemetry_poller, "~> 1.0"},
      {:gettext, "~> 0.18"},
      {:jason, "~> 1.2"},
      {:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.5"}
    ]
  end
```

After that I created a LiveView page and added this example code to it:

```elixir
  def hide_modal(js \\ %JS{}) do
    js
    |> JS.hide(transition: "fade-out", to: "#modal")
    |> JS.hide(transition: "fade-out-scale", to: "#modal-content")
  end
```

Starting the server fails:

```
$ mix phx.server
Compiling 1 file (.ex)

== Compilation error in file lib/demo3_web/live/stock_watch_live.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/demo3_web/live/stock_watch_live.ex:66: JS.__struct__/1 is undefined, cannot expand struct JS. Make sure the struct name is correct. If the struct name exists and is correct but it still cannot be found, you likely have cyclic module usage in your code
    lib/demo3_web/live/stock_watch_live.ex:66: (module)
```

What do I have to add/change to fix this?

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to alias some other module, e.g. `alias Javascript, as: JS` ?

Comment: I think what is missing at the top of the file where you define `hide_modal` is `alias Phoenix.LiveView.JS `

Comment: This link https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/4642 may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `alias Phoenix.LiveView.JS` on top of the file solves the problem. Thanks to @scott-thompson!

The docs have just been updated.
https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_view/commit/a0b39649ce6f02561033fd42c7205644fe3a706b#diff-a095f1aa9c79bb58142c5628142a5ddc52bb344547400409a8c6a3237896cedc

Comment: note you might have to update phoenix_live_view and phoenix_live_dashboard too. I think this was added with phoenix_live_view 0.17